# FTP won't open a connection to client

Tags: ftp, kvm-virtualization, openstack

I am running Windows server 2008 on Ubuntu server 12.04.1 via devstack and I am trying to download a file from an ftp server using the windows command line ftp client.

When I run the ftp get command I get the following error message:

> 500 I won't open a connection to 10.0.0.2 (only to XX.XX.XX.XX)
>   425 No data connection

`10.0.0.2` is the internal IP address of the instance, whereas `XX.XX.XX.XX` is the external address. Is there anyway to make the ftp client use the external address for the data connection, or alternatively have the client establish the connection?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you want to use Passive FTP. For some reason it's not a command line option anymore. Go to:

Control Panel,
Internet Options,
Advanced,
Browser Options section,
Use passive FTP